# Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem clarification

Tags: probability-theory

I reading Klenke's - Probability Theory book and having some trouble following this proof. Here is the theorem:

[image]

This is how the proof starts:

[image]

And here is theorem 1.18 for your convenience, it just says that $\pi$-system implies $\sigma$-algebra under certain conditions.

[image]

So in our proof we just need to show that $\delta(\mathcal{E})$ is a $\pi$-system. The proof then says that is enough to show that $\delta(\mathcal{E}) \subset \mathcal{D}_B$ for any $B \in \delta(\mathcal{E})$. And this is precisely what I do not understand. i.e. how can something that is a larger collection of sets be a subset of something that is smaller...

Here is how it goes in the book:

[image]

Comment: What is $\delta$? Also the proof doesn't imply $D_B$ is larger than $\delta$, only that $\delta$ is contained in $D_B$, (clearly they must be equal after asserting $\delta\subset D_B$).

Comment: it is a $\lambda$-system generated by $\mathcal{E}$

Comment: Many authors use $A\subset B$ and $A\subseteq B$ interchangeably. Usually, when we want to say that $A$ is a *proper* subset of $B$, we will be explicit.

Comment: but how can that be the case. What about the following argument:
1) If $\delta(\mathcal{E}) \subseteq \mathcal{D}_B$ for some B, then how can it be a proper subset for some other $A \in \delta({\mathcal{E}})$, unless of course, the set $\mathcal{D}_A \subseteq \mathcal{D}_B$

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: If I were you, I wouldn't complain for the use of $\subset$ in place of $\subseteq$. I would complain for the use of $\delta(\mathcal E)$ to denote the $\lambda$ system generated by $\mathcal E$; that should be $\lambda(\mathcal E)$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove that the $\lambda$-system generated by $\mathcal{E}$ - denoted $\delta(\mathcal{E})$ - is a $\sigma$-algebra, we want to prove that it is closed under pairwise intersections.  That is, if $E,F\in\delta(E)$, then $E\cap F\in\delta(E)$.  Fix $E\in\delta(E)$.  Saying that $F\cap E\in\delta(\mathcal{E})$ for every $F\in \delta(\mathcal{E})$ is the same as saying that $\{F\subset X : E\cap F \in \delta(P)\}$ contains every element of $\delta(E)$. It changes nothing in the previous sentence to do as your book does and consider $\mathcal{D}_E = \{F\in \delta(\mathcal{E}) : F\cap E \in \delta(\mathcal{E})\}$, since we only care about $\delta(\mathcal{E})$ and not arbitrary subsets of $X$.

Note: the notation $A\subset B$ does not exclude the case that $A = B$.  Here, it is going to be true that $\mathcal{D}_E = \delta(\mathcal{E})$.  The common notation for being a proper subset is $A\subsetneq B$.